# What statistical analyses would you use to analyze the change across two time points, months apart?

Tags: pre-post-comparison, growth-model

I will be administering an early literacy assessment to preschoolers at 2 time points in the preschool year. I want to be able to examine the growth from point A to point B. I also wanted to administer a social emotional assessment at the two time points and asses for growth as well. Lastly, I wanted to examine correlation amongst the two.

I had initially thought of a growth model but realize two time points may not be appropriate for this type of model. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen so helpful thank you!